# What will be the best way to create a ecommerce app with Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, e-commerce

I'm wondering what will be the best way if I wanted to create a ecommerce app from scratch with Symfony ?

What will be the starting point ? What will be the schema of the app ? How to implement a cart and order bundle ?

Thank you.

Comment: The starting point is requirement gathering

Comment: Waaaaaay to broad...

Comment: Voted to close as it's a totally off-topic question for StackOverflow. PS: The only starting point you should follow is start to learn the programming basics and then take a look at the code of the many open source projects already built to see the different solutions implemented to solve many common e-commerce requirements.

Comment: For your next questions please, go to the [Help Section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then, if you are sure your question fits the SO rules, read [How to Ask a question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to be able to make a good, well formed and on-topic question.

Comment: ok @gp_sflover I understand. I hesitated before posting my question because I knew it wasn't the best place... Thank you for the reminder. I will test my chance on Quora. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You can watch http://sylius.org/, it's a ecommerce solution based on symfony

Comment: Hey ! I know sylius but what if I want to build something from scratch ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't suggest to create an ecommerce solution from scratch. There are many legal requirements, such as privacy policies, you have to met and they differ from country to country. They are already solved by existing solutions.